# parametrize the boundary of a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, surface-integrals, parametrization

I need to parametrize the boundary of this region :

$D=\{y^2+z^2\le x^2+18,x^2+y^2\le 16\}$

So It's a one-sheet hyperboloid (radius=$\sqrt{18}$)+ cylinder with radius 4

I know how to parametrize them separately:

hyperboloid : $r(\theta,\phi)=(\sinh\phi,\sqrt{18}sin\theta\cosh{\phi},\sqrt{18}cos\theta\cosh{\phi})$

cylinder: $r(\theta,z)=(4\cos\theta,4\sin\theta,z)$

But how do I connect them? Ho do I parametrize the surface boundary?

Or maybe "parametrize the boundary" implies giving two parametrizations?If it is so, are my parametrizations right?

Comment: Apologies about delayed post. Shall post parameterizations and image tomorrow. Basically you are drilling/ intersecting a hyperboloid of 1 sheet with a cylinder.. There are two distorted "circular" disks produced. You can consider  1) the remaining continuous shell after drilling out the cylindrical holes   or 2) the two discs themselves as the region depending on what you want to evaluate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider at first equalities. There are two surfaces of revolution $(a=\sqrt{18},b=4 )$

$$  y^2+z^2-x^2=a^2 $$

$$ y^2+z^2=b^2  $$

which are hyperboloid of one sheet and a circular cylinder respectively.

Intersection of surfaces is the boundary of region for further purposes of integration etc.

Eliminate $y$ we get for $z$

$$ z = \sqrt{ 2x^2+a^2-b^2 } \tag1 $$

Circle of radius $b$ in projection is parameterized as $ (x,y)= b(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) $ and for $z$ we obtain by plugging in from above (1)

$$ z=\pm \sqrt{ 2 b^2 \cos^2 \theta +(a^2-b^2)}$$

The connected regions and the surfaces that created them along with (white) lines of intersection are plotted in *Mathematica* below .

Note that when two conicoids intersect we can generally have

1. Null real intersection ( disjunct surfaces)
2. One real closed loop intersection
3. Two real intersections

depending on distance of centers of central conicoids. In each case we can refer  to the patches so created *arbitrarily* connecting them as internal or external to intersection contour made or defined by the equality. Each sign defines its own boundary of demarcated intersection, which enables determining regions where inequalities apply.

To find demarcation and connection a sketch is often helpful in guiding the region continuity of the patch in reference.

So the parameterizations are same but for $\pm$ sign where *each sign represents a region.*

The situation is no different if you consider intersection of a big cylinder and a smaller cylinder regions so created!

[image: Boundary of Intrxn]

Comment: could you give me the actual parametrization, please?

Comment: They are given after (1) above.

Comment: Thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

$x=4\cos(t),y=4\sin(t),z=\sqrt{16\cos(2t)+18},\; 0 \leq t\leq2\pi$.
[image]

$x=4\cos(t),y=4\sin(t),z=-\sqrt{16\cos(2t)+18},\; 0 \leq t\leq2\pi$.
[image]

This is surface boundary parametrization.

Comment: this is a curve parametrization? or a surface parametrization?

Comment: how did you find z?

Comment: @NPLS  $z^2=x^2-y^2+18=16\cos^2t-16\sin^2t+18=16\cos2t+18$.